# avoid "HTTP Error 418: You look like a robot"

Tags: screen-scraping, pythonanywhere

I have a script that crawls a homepage with urllib:

```
url = "https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/..."
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
```

If i run the script on my PC I have no problems, if I run it on pythonanywhere.com I get:

> HTTP Error 418: You look like a robot

As it works on my PC the reason is probably the known IP from pythonanywhere.com. Is this correct and how could I avoid this?

Comment: It may well be the IP address, yes.  Some sites block cloud providers because they don't want people scraping their data.   You might be able to work around it using a proxy...?

Comment: Yes, I used a proxy and this solved the issue. Thank you.