# How to avoid resulted in a `418 You look like a robot (4)

Tags: php, guzzle

I am using guzzle php library to scrape the data from other sites.
PHP script without proxy

```
 $httpClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $httpClient->get($url);
$htmlString = (string) $response->getBody();
```

But when I am using a proxy I am facing the 504 gateway time out error.

Script with proxy:

```
 $httpClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['proxy' => 'http://92.51.77.126']); 
 $response = $httpClient->get($url);
 $htmlString = (string) $response->getBody();
```

**Referance:** https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#proxy

Comment: lol... gotcha - you ARE a robot! Obviously the site you're trying to scrape doesn't like that...

Comment: Perhaps the target site already has the proxy IP on a blacklist ...

Comment: Why do you state different HTTP errors in title and content?

Comment: @CBroe I am scrapping the data from ebay. Is there any other solution to do this?

Comment: Talk to the site owner, and ask under what conditions they might be willing to share their data with you, using a proper API ...? If a site employs such measures to begin with, then you should take that as a good indicator that they probably don't want anyone _stealing_ their data using automated tools.

Comment: @CBroe It is almost a similar question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49243020/avoid-http-error-418-you-look-like-a-robot
And he resolved the issue by proxy but don't know how.

Comment: Just because two sites respond with the same HTTP status in a situation like this, does not mean they necessarily employ the same techniques when it comes to "bot detection."

Comment: So the only solution is contacting eBay support in order to resolve this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just found a solution.
I have bought a premium proxy and used it as a describe in the github issues.

```php
$httpClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'proxy' => 'username:password@IP:Port', //use without "socks5://" scheme
    'verify' => true, // used only for SSL check , u can set false too for not check
    'curl' => [CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE => 7],
]);

$response = $httpClient->get($url);
$htmlString = (string) $response->getBody();
```

**Simler Issue:** https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1484